# Why does my mail server reject mail from a particular domain?

Tags: postfix

Below is an excerpt from the log:

```
exchngdel postfix/smtpd[11617]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[220.77.94.202]: 554 5.7.1 <unknown[220.77.94.202]>: Client host rejected: Access denied; from=<aldobarban@electrotech.ca> to=<a@ltd.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<samsung-45fa307.kornet>
```

Comment: You're going to need to give us a *lot* more info, your main.conf would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

`Client host rejected: Access denied` is the result of an smtpd_client_restrictions rejection, such as a `check_client_access` result of REJECT, or a ruleset of `permit_mynetworks, reject`.

Beyond that, we can't possibly tell you, since you provide no information whatsoever.

Include the output from `postconf -n` in your question, as well as the *complete* logs from a single message or connection that is rejected.